# Issue with max_user_connections in web app hosted live

Tags: php, mysql

I have recently put a PHP / MySQL web app live on a hosted platform, and keep getting this error...

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1203): User [redacted] already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections in [redacted] on line 4 Database connection failed: User [redacted] already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections (1203)

When I run "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections'" I get 1024, and when I run "SHOW STATUS WHERE variable_name = 'threads_connected';" I get around 51.

Am I looking at the right thing? My host cannot increase the max_user_connections. How can I resolve this???

Comment: Check if your application is using persistent connections. Persistent connections don't close when the execution of your script ends. If you're using a lot of them, they can quickly eat up all available connections. Ensure that your application closes its database connections when they're no longer needed. In PHP, this can be done using the mysqli_close($connection) function.
Use connection pooling if possible. This allows your application to reuse existing connections rather than creating a new one for every request.

Comment: I definitely close connections with mysqli_close($connection) at the footer of every page. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: You show an error message, but not the code that causes that error message. Anything anyone offers as a solution is just a guess. You could be opening many connections per PHP request, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278195/). You could be opening a connection and holding on to it for a long time, if your PHP requests take too long to complete. There's no way to know given the information you have provided.

Comment: Sorry Bill, I'm not sure what code I'd show. It's a very large application and I've been running it via an onsite server for years with no issue. It's only now I'm hosting it outside the premises it's having issues. Thank you though, I will dig deeper into the code.